# TabView primefaces 3.1 Reload a page inside a tab and call again the ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, tabs, primefaces, tabview

I need some help, I'm using primefaces 3.1 and doing some pages, and I want to load this pages into a tabview, and each page depends of each other.

Like This.

```
<p:tabView id="tabView1">
        <p:tab id="tabInfo" title="title1">
            <ui:include src="page1.xhtml"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tab2" title="title2" >
            <ui:include src="page2.xhtml"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tab3" title="title3">
            <ui:include src="page3.xhtml"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

page 2 depends form page 1 for making some validations and present or not the page 2 this information, page3 need the same.

How can I do for when I select tab2 call again the ManagedBean of page 2 and reload page 2 and make that validations and present the data?.

This validations and all the serach of the information is on the init Method.

Please help me with this.

And I apologize for my poor english.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add something like this to your tabView:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView1">
     <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{yourBean.onTabChange}" update=":tab2"/>
...
```

- event: defines what should happen to start the ajax request
- listener: will be notified if the event happens
- update: does a re-render on the given id

---

Update to answer your comment:

The method *onTabChange* could look like this:

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {  
    // ... 
}
```

*event* provides the selected tab:

```
event.getTab()
```

you could now rerender all of your tabs with:

```
... update=":tabInfo, :tab2, :tab3"
```

or you store the selected tab in your bean and do something like this:

```
... update="#{yourBean.selectedTab}"
```

where *selectedTab* would look like this:

```
public String getSelectedTab(){
     // selectedTab is a variable that should be set onTabChange()
     return selectedTab;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what happen If I need to reload page on tab3, and what should be inside method onTabChange?

Comment: Thanks very much I would try this.